# HTTPS redirect with wildcard cerificate

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, https, virtualhost

Apache 2.2. I have an wildcard SSL Certificate to `*.mydomain.com`. I want to allow secure connections also directly at `mydomain.com`. I have found a solution that I can make the address for my site `www.mydomain.com` only, and indeed - certificate is working when I enter `www.mydomain.com`. Working configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.der
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/key.pem

    // site config, redirects to Apache Tomcat
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.mydomain.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.der
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/key.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enter the `http://mydomain.com` and `http://www.mydomain.com` I am redirected to the `https://www.mydomain.com` as expected.

However, when I enter `https://mydomain.com`, the browser says that the certificate is invalid (padlock is red). I have to confirm that I know and trust the certificate (in chrome it is called "add a security exception") and after it - I am properly redirected to the `https://www.mydomain.com` - and the padlock is green.

Question is: how to redirect `https://mydomain.com` to `https://www.mydomain.com` without bothering user about invalid certificate?

I tried to remove the `SSL*` entries from the second `VirtualHost` definition, but then apache does not start and the following message is in logs:

```
[error] Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured 
[Hint: SSLCertificateFile] (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain:1)
```

Comment: Does your certificate have SAN entries for both `*.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com`? (By the way, using a *permanent* redirect when you're trying out various configuration settings isn't necessarily a good idea, since the browser you test it with is likely to remember it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSL connect with the certificate verification will be done before any HTTP messages are exchanged. Thus a HTTP redirect from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com can only be done after successful verification of the certificate. Therefore no fiddling with the server will help and your only choice is to get a certificate which does include mydomain.com.